# Trying to produce a maze from a text file using c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, char

So far I am able to read from my text file. I then go on to try access each line. From here I try access each value in the line. If it is a 1 I will create a game object on position x = 1 and if the next one is a 1 that object will be places position x = 2. Once this line has been read I want to change position from y=0 (the first row) to y=1 and so forth.

My problem is that when I try run this I only seem to get the first value from each row. Could someone have a look at my code and tell me where my brainfart lies? I would greatly appreciate it :)!

```
//Splits each line to be accessed easily
            eachLine = File.ReadAllLines("Maze1.txt");

            //Gets number of lines
            int lines = File.ReadAllLines("Maze1.txt").Length;

            // Accesses each line one at a time
            foreach (string line in eachLine)
            {
                // Accessess each character in each line one at a time


            foreach(char c in line)
            {
                string currentNum = c.ToString();
                thisNum = Convert.ToInt32(currentNum);
                //Console.WriteLine("This Number: {0}",thisNum)

                    if (thisNum != 1)
                    {

                        //While i 
                        while(i < lines)
                        {
                            ObjectSpawnPosition = new Vector3(i+1,0,0);
                            Console.WriteLine("This num is 1");
                            Instantiate(obj, ObjectSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: For starters you're reading the file a second time just to get the number of lines when you can get it from `eachLine.Length`.

Comment: Hehe thanks for that :) I'm very new to all this stuff so each little bit of advice really does help!

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want to do at each position in your file.  You say you create an object if the character is 1, but you have a `if(thisNum != 1)`.  Then you have a while loop using an `i` variable that you don't even show where it is declared.

Comment: Oh yeah that is meant to be thisNum ==1 I was just fooling around with the code trying to figure out where the problem lies. i is declared at the top as public int i = 0;

Comment: depending on where `i` is declared it's going to be incremented until it equals `lines` and then for the next character it will just skip the `while` loop.  I'm guessing at the very least you need to have a `i=0;` before the `while` loop to reset it for each character in the file.  But again I don't understand the need to loop once for every line in the file for each character in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is how you're looping. If you read a 1, you loop over lines and create an object for every line. Instead you should do this:

```
int y = 0;

// Accesses each line one at a time
foreach (string line in eachLine)
{
    // reset the x position to the beginning of each line.
    int x = 0;

    // Accesses each character in each line one at a time
    foreach(char c in line)
    {
        string currentNum = c.ToString();
        thisNum = Convert.ToInt32(currentNum);

        if (thisNum == 1)
        {
            // Create a single object at x,y (no looping here)
            ObjectSpawnPosition = new Vector3(x,y,0);
            Instantiate(obj, ObjectSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        // increment x inside the inner loop.
        x++;
    }
    // done with a line, so increment y to go to the next line.
    y++;
}
```